# How to update a SQL table based on record count no of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables named as `Share` and `Balance`. `users` is common column in both table.  There are multiple rows/share for each user in `Share` table.

What I need to do is update `paid` column from `Share` table by adding 1 on each share and that added count no needs to be added in `balance` column of  `Balance` table. Say, a user has 3 rows/shares in `Share` table and if i add +1 for each share then in `balance` column of `Balance` table needs to add 3 with existing balance.

I have written following sql statement. It is updating `Share` table accordingly but `Balance` table is updating wrong. See the image below:

[image: table share]

```
Update Share Set paid=paid + 1
Update Balance Set balance=balance + S.Paid
From balance B,share S Where B.users=S.users
```

Comment: Please can you give your example in a tabular format? Show the data before and the expected result after the update.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results in a *tabular* format.

Comment: hi thanks , i have added an image describing my table

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Share Set paid=paid + 1
Update Balance Set balance=balance + (select count(S.Paid) From balance B,share S 
                                     Where B.users=S.users
                                     group by s.users )
From balance B,share S Where B.users=S.users

--If increment is always +1 in share table then this query will work fine.
```

Comment: you can make it generic by multiplying it with actual increment rather than considering increment is always +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use two select.

For readblity  is better the explicit join sintax
and if you use alias you should use the table alias  in all the columns name

```
Update Share 
Set paid=paid + 1;

Update Balance B
INNER JOIN (
  select users, count(*) an num_count
  from share
  group by user
  ) t on t.users = B.users
Set B.balance=B.balance + t.num_count;
```

Comment: Problem with second update statement is that it updates taking the present paid value.say a user has 7 in paid and if i run above statement then it ads 7 to the balance but it should be balance+no.of share*1

Comment: update your question add  a  clear data sample and the expected  result  .

Comment: Pls see my image i have added

Comment: thnks but it is giving me an error incorrect syntex near ')'  i dont understand what is single s and t in your statement